# How does Encryption on MySQL work MySQL version 5.7?

Tags: mysql, encryption

Following steps are followed to enable MySQL encryption.

1. Mysql version 5.7 is installed on apache server. So by default `keyring_file.so` is available at following path: `/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/keyring_file`.
2. In **/etc/my.cnf** below 2 code is added and MySQL is restarted.

> ```
> early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so
>
> keyring_file_data=/var/lib/mysql-keyring/keyring
> ```

3. When below query is executed to check if keyring plugin is active. It outputs as active

> `SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE 'keyring%';`
>
> ```
> +--------------+---------------+
> | PLUGIN_NAME  | PLUGIN_STATUS |
> +--------------+---------------+
> | keyring_file | ACTIVE        |
> +--------------+---------------+
> ```

4. Encryption is enabled on table level (on table author of DB testDB), It can be checked using below query

> ```
> SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CREATE_OPTIONS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE CREATE_OPTIONS LIKE '%ENCRYPTION%';
>
> +--------------+------------+----------------+
> | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | CREATE_OPTIONS |
> +--------------+------------+----------------+
> | testDB       | author     | ENCRYPTION="Y" |
> +--------------+------------+----------------+
> ```

5. Data is inserted in **author** table as "plain text". However, though the table is encrypted.

> ```
> select * from author;
>
> +------+----------+-------------+
> | id   | name     | email       |
> +------+----------+-------------+
> |    1 | PQR      | xuz@abc.com |
> |    1 | XYZ      | abc@abc.com |
> |    1 | SSSS     | xyz@abc.com |
> |    1 | dfdfdf   | prq@abc.com |
> +------+----------+-------------+
> ```

What needs to be done to enable encryption on MySQL table?

Comment: "Mysql version 5.7 is installed on apache server" - Is that a typo?

Comment: this is transparent database encryption - it encrypts the data in the data file on the fly and decrypts it on retrieval by an authenticated user

Answer (score 2):

What you enabled was [innodb data at rest encryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-data-encryption.html), which is a transparent encryption technique, meaning authenticated and authorised users will not even notice it. As the [mysql FAQ says on decryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-tablespace-encryption.html#faq-tablespace-encryption-access):

> InnoDB data-at-rest encryption is designed to transparently apply encryption within the database without impacting existing applications. Returning data in encrypted format would break most existing applications. InnoDB data-at-rest encryption provides the benefit of encryption without the overhead associated with traditional database encryption solutions, which would typically require expensive and substantial changes to applications, database triggers, and views.